# App registration in Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to register the app from my desktop app into Azure AD, my desktop app is using Microsoft Graph API.

How to register the app in AD without manual intervention in the Azure portal?

Comment: If it helps you, don’t forget to click the tick next to the answer to change it from gray to filled.

Comment: Is there an update?

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple, you only need to call the [create application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)  graph api, you can also set [other properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) of the application in the request body when creating the application.

You can use [graph-explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to call the api directly, which requires you to have **Application.ReadWrite.All** permission.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an App Registration if you use the Azure Resource Manager API (AzureRM API). There is an endpoint where you you apply the App Registration request and it will be created. You should of course be very sure of what you do here. And you can only do that by first getting an elevated access token for an admin user (I think it's valid for 5mins) by prompting the user/adminconsent. It must be a global admin or a user that has access to do this I'm the Azure portal. But without the hazzle of actually clicking around in the portal.